# How to stop Firefox 52 ESR from auto-updating?

Tags: firefox, java, software-update, auto-updates

I am trying to download the Firefox 52.9.0 ESR (32-bit) as it can run Java as a plugin in the browser. I've been doing this by taking the zip file from the [archive](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/), extracting it to my desired folder, then running `firefox.exe`. This works fine for the first session, but in order to complete installing the latest Java, I have to close Firefox and start a new session, upon which it automatically updates to Firefox Quantum 60.2.0 ESR, which I don't want. It does this even when I have set the update setting to 'ask for updates but let me choose to install' within the first session. How can I prevent this from happening, and instead keep Firefox 52.9.0 ESR?

EDIT: I fixed it by changing the update settings to 'never check for updates'. However, upon starting my 2nd session, it still tried to update, but gave an error something along the lines of 'update failed (failed to apply update patch)'. Luckily this error message doesn't seem to appear at the start of new sessions. Weird that it tries to automatically update, even though I've set it not to.

Comment: I need Java in my browser, and I have reluctantly abandoned Firefox in favour of the forks Waterfox and PaleMoon, both of which which retain the necessary NPAPI support and run FF plug-ins, albeit not the latest versions.

Comment: @AFH, consider posting that as an answer (with product links).  I was just going to suggest that as a solution since they are supported while pre-Quantum Firefox is not, which addresses the risks.  I haven't actually tried them, though, so you are in a better position to describe your experience.

Answer (score 2):

I need Java in my browser, and I have reluctantly abandoned Firefox in favour of the forks [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/) and [PaleMoon](http://palemoon.org/), both of which which retain the NPAPI support which Java needs.

Both run Firefox plug-ins, albeit not the latest versions, and it is these that have kept me in the Firefox family, rather than switching to Chrome - having got used to them, I find it difficult to manage without TabMixPlus, All-in-One Sidebar and FireFTP, in particular.

PaleMoon was forked earlier than Waterfox, but it has its own Add-ons site, and while I also use extensions from the main Mozilla extensions site, I need to search for compatible versions.

Waterfox is more recent and uses the standard Mozilla extensions site, and in many cases the latest versions will install, but being less established it has a few more quirks than PaleMoon.

As far as add-ons are concerned, most of the updates have been to handle Firefox updates, rather than security fixes, so I am not concerned at using earlier versions.

PaleMoon is 32/64-bit, while Waterfox is 64-bit only. On Windows there are install and portable versions - Waterfox portable is [PortableApps](https://portableapps.com/)-compatible, although for some reason is not included on the the PortableApps site, which means that it is adopted into the menu system, but doesn't update automatically. There are Linux versions of both and there are repositories available for Debian-derived systems.

Comment: Ah, yes; I hadn't thought about the "legacy" add-ons becoming unavailable.  One option would be to go directly to the developers' site if the old add-on is no longer available through the browser's add-on list.  The developer may no longer be actively supporting it, but you can often find the last available version still downloadable.

Comment: @fixer1234 "legacy/XUL" addons are not anymore available at Mozilla servers. However, the repository was forked and there is an addon (Classic Addons Archive) which allow you to install and see addons information in a similar way than Mozilla´s Addons page. https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/releases

Comment: @DanielPerez - I have not loaded any new add-ons for some time, so thanks for pointing out that legacy extensions have now been removed from the main Mozilla site and for the alternative, which I shall investigate shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Needless to say, using an outdated browser is a security risk, much like running Windows XP past April 2014. If you do not know how to mitigate known unpatched security bugs then you should not be using an unsupported web browser.

If you don't want a legacy browser updating by itself, then you need to turn off automatic updates before the browser ever gets online in the first place.

In your case, you should have entered the legacy FF's [profile manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) with the `-P` switch, created a new profile, and ticked `[Work offline]` before starting the browser, which would have given you time to disable automatic updates before the browser started downloading them in the background on first run.

Manual edits to the configuration files within the browser profile are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm willing to take the risk.

Comment: Sorry, also meant to add:  The browser only started trying to download updates on the second run, therefore I didn't need to use the profile manager to work offline upon the first run to disable updates - I could disable them on the first run directly.

Answer (score 0):

So you're connected to the internet when you first run the browser, it's initial settings are to update, so it updates while/before you can change the update settings.

How about just disconnect from the internet entirely (software disconnect, disable all networking, pull plug/adapter) for the first run, change the update settings & exit, then reconnect to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

We need to run java-based tests with a static IP address through a browser with
NPAPI java support, so with the likes of seamonkey dropping support,
Firefox ESR 52.9.0 is still being used for this, and still is by others I
suspect.

Firefox ESR completely ignores this setting:

Tools/Options/Advanced/Update/'Never check for updates (not recommended: security risk)'

It also appears to ignore most if not all of the update settings in
about:config, so here is what I have found that works, in order of
effectiveness. Be sure to make these changes BEFORE Firefox runs for the
first time if you have just installed/downgraded to 52.9.0 ESR.

#1
Delete/rename this file

C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\updater.exe

Without it the browser won't be able to update, no matter how hard it tries,
although I suspect this will not kill all possible update routes.

#2
Find this file

C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\channel-prefs.js

and edit the "esr" bit at the bottom to someting like "DONOTUPDATE"
Doesn't matter what you change it to, as long as its a channel that doesn't exist.

#3
Similarly, find this file

C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\update-settings.ini

and edit the
ACCEPTED_MAR_CHANNEL_IDS
value also to a channel that does not exist, like
ACCEPTED_MAR_CHANNEL_IDS=DONOTUPDATE

#4
Finally, unticking Tools/Options/Advanced/Update/'Use a background service to
install updates' disables this background service. All this service does is
bypass the UAC prompt that would pop up whenever a new Firefox update that has
been downloaded is being applied, thus making the update process 'silent',
and it doesn't do any downloading or updating of Firefox on its own.
Still, you can remove it completely if you want as it has its own entry
'Mozilla Maintenance Service' in 'Add/remove Programs' (XP) or
'Programs and Features' (Win10), so can easily be uninstalled.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the Mozilla Maintenance service from the system, it won't update automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Can you elaborate on how one goes about removing the Mozilla Maintenance service?  I tried turning it counterclockwise to unscrew it and nothing happened.